# SQL Server Views with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have created a view called `view_SelectAll_Student` in SQL Server which retrieves all columns from single table name

And I have a function that returns dataset or datatable using dataadapter somehow I get this error:

> The request for procedure 'view_SellectAll_Student' failed because 'view_SellectAll_Student' is a view object.

Code:

```
public DataTable ViewStudentAll() 
{
      cons.Open();

      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      cmd = new SqlCommand("view_SellectAll_Student", cons);
      cmd.Connection = cons;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

      adp.Fill(dt);
      cmd.Dispose();
      cons.Close();
      adp.Dispose();

      return dt; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this. If its a view you should SELECT it otherwise you wont get it.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM view_SellectAll_Student",cons);
cmd.Connection = cons;
//cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(dt);
cmd.Dispose();
cons.Close();
adp.Dispose();
return dt;
```

TIP: While using a `DataAdapter` there is no need of `con.Open()` or `con.Close()` statement. `DataAdapter` itself will open and close it.

Answer (score 1):

Views still need to be queried. What you have here is just the view name..

So change this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("view_SellectAll_Student",cons);
```

to this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT put, columns, here FROM view_SellectAll_Student",cons);
```

Make sure you put the columns of the view there (or an asterisk.. if you're that way inclined).

Answer (score 0):

> The SqlDataAdapter accepts as first argument an SqlCommand which can
>   be a  Select statement or stored procedure.

In this case you can replace "view_SellectAll_Student" with

```
"Select * from view_SellectAll_Student"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cons.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmd = new SqlCommand("select * view_SellectAll_Student",cons);
cmd.Connection = cons;
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(dt);
cmd.Dispose();
cons.Close();
adp.Dispose();
return dt;
```